# PolygonHotSpot vs RectangleHotSpot; Can't select all of PolygonHotSpot?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, polygon, imagemap

I am programatically creating an `ImageMap` using VB.NET and then adding `PolygonHotSpot`s to it. It kind of works, but I notice when I hover my mouse over the `PolygonHotSpot`, there are parts/spots inside that **aren't** selectable (the mouse cursor changes from the hand to the default cursor).

The coordinates I'm adding to my `PolygonHotSpot` are (which for this example is simple rectangle):

> 150,99,270,213,270,99,150,213

I noticed when I change this to a `RectangleHotSpot`, and set the `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left`, `Right` based on those same coordinates, it works perfectly, and there aren't any parts inside that aren't selectable. The reason I need to be using `PolygonHotSpot` rather than `RectangleHotSpot` is because each hotspot could have more than 4 sides (it will be different every time).

Am I doing something wrong, or should I be checking that if I only have 4 coordinates to go ahead and convert it to a `RectangleHotSpot`? Or has anyone had any experience with a `PolygonHotSpot`, maybe I'm missing a setting? I've got the `HotSpotMode` set to PostBack, etc (everything that worked for the `RectangleHotSpot`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not drawing a rectangle, but an X. If you put your coordinates in clockwise order IIRC, you will get your rectangle.

Actually, the clockwise order doesn't seem to matter, but the order does:

"150,99,270,99,270,213,150,213" should work.

Comment: wow, yep that was it. Right after I posted this I wondered if the order of the coordinates mattered. Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: @lhanneman: You're welcome; glad I could help. Welcome to the community, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I've got one more question about PolygonHotSpots. I had to ask it in a separate question as it wouldn't fit in my comment. :) My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878124/help-drawing-polygonhotspot-coordinates-around-two-rectangles. Thanks in advance for any help! It's much appreciated.