# Draw PolygonHotSpot around two Rectangles?

Tags: vb.net, polygon, imagemap

Lets say that I've got the coordinates of two `Rectangle`s, they could be right next to each other or have space between them. I need to draw a `PolygonHotSpot` around the two rectangles (so it will only cover the two rectangles and the space between them). I've come to find that I have to give the coordinates a clockwise order around the entire polygon, rather than around each rectangle (which works fine for a single rectangle).

So given a list of coordinates, is there a way to get them into the order that I need for there to not be any gaps in my `PolygonHotSpot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `Union` of the two:

```
    Dim R1 As New Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 100)
    Dim R2 As New Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100)
    Dim R3 = Rectangle.Union(R1, R2) '//R3 = 20, 20, 280, 280
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for. Rectangle.Union creates the smallest possible rectangle around the two given rectangles. I need to use the two sets of coordinates and apply them to a PolygonHotSpot so that the only clickable area is on the rectangles, rather than the entire area around the two. Hopefully that makes sense, it's easier to draw on paper.

Comment: I'm wondering if I'd just be better off drawing two separate RectangleHotSpots, that way I can use the coordinates I've got, and then have them map to the same URL. Then there wouldn't be any space in between the two that are selectable.

Comment: @lhanneman, I've spent way more time than I should (I'm at work right now) on this because its a fun problem but I think I'd agree with your idea of just drawing two image maps. You could also check to see if the rectangle intersect and if they don't draw a third rectangle that connects them.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do! I appreciate the help!